Is it possible to set "Global Environment Variables" for docker-compose?
Is there a way to dictate "Environment Variables" for Docker-Compose in a system wide manner (with in the boundaries of Docker environment ofc) so they would be globally accessible?
As I understand one can set Environment Variables with-in each and every .yml for each and every container. I wonder if those EV could be in one file and could be called upon from each and every .yml for all/any .yml for any docker-compose.yml.
I hope I am describing this in a correct manner.
Initially I tried to figure this out by asking over at GitHub, Docker / Compose but haven't got any replies so I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask here as well. In that post the details around the why is described as well.

Not to my knowledge. One of the points of containers is isolation. But you can make a service in a container that holds the values you need to share. Something like Redis can probably do that pretty easily. Then the other containers can fetch the value from there.

What you describe in the github post is typically done with a .env file in the same directory as your compose file.  If you really wanted to you could put a wrapper script around docker compose that passes in —env-file .  This way it would be done automatically for every compose run.  Seems silly though.  Not sure of any built in way to achieve what you want.
